# Using hardware layer acceleration and will-change properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, hardware-acceleration

I want to animate 100+ DOM elements across the viewport when dragged horizontally by using CSS `translate3d` property and `requestAnimationFrame`. The example is [over here](http://codesketch.gnikoloff.com).

Since it's a rather big collection of dom nodes, I am animating them only if it is their turn to enter the scene, otherwise I set them to `display: none` and dont touch them.

Here is my code for initialization:

```
makePoints (num) {
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
        this.points.push({
            x: i * this.spacing,
            y: window.innerHeight / 2 + Math.sin(i * this.spacing) * 100 - 80,
            scale: 0.5 + Math.random() * 0.5
        });
        this.totalWidth += this.spacing;
    }
}
```

and here is my frame update method:

```
update (speed) {
    this.points.forEach((p, i) => {
        let li = this.domCollection[i];

        if (p.x > -this.spacing && p.x < this.width) {
            $(li).css({
                transform: `
                    translate3d(${p.x}px, ${p.y}px, 0) 
                    scale(${p.scale}, ${p.scale})
                `,
                display: 'block'
            });
        } else {
            $(li).css({
                display: 'none'
            })
        }

        p.x += -speed;

        if (p.x <= -this.width) {
            p.x += this.totalWidth;
        } else if (p.x >= this.totalWidth - this.width) {
            p.x -= this.totalWidth;
        }

    });
}
```

My question is: in this case, am I utilizing hardware acceleration properly? As soon as the first time the element gets into the viewport, `translate3d` is used on it and it is hardware accelerated at this moment? Should I put `will-change: transform` on all of them or should I toggle it on / off when updating the `display`?

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this acelleration concept, any help is more then appreciated.

Comment: I think as long as you are using translate3d it is using hardware acceleration

Comment: Yeah, but isn't this kind of abusing hardware acceleration? Is it optimal to apply it to such a big collection of dom nodes simultaneously?

Comment: Well of course it will be better if you can apply to fewer elements but if your code does not allow that then what else can you do? If you can wrap the items in one container it would be better

Comment: Unfortunately this way I will loose the option to loop items when the end is reached... but how about toggling will-change on and off when the element is visible / hidden?